# how to make radio button disappear on item select from spinner

Tags: java, android

```
rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
rb2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
rb3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
rb4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
rb5=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton5);

spiner1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spiner2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1); 

spiner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

This is my code  there are 5 value in my spiner if i select  first one then rb1,rb2,rb3,rb5 shud display  and rest disappear if i select 2,3,4,5 value from spinner then it hud display 1st,4,5 plz tell me how to write code for this i m new in android try to implement some apps. i need code where and how to apply logic for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are some demos about spinner
[Here is an example.](http://imshare.iteye.com/blog/770950)
you can set dropdown styles in this method

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your condition or logic you can show/hide buttons.

```
rb1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   // show
rb2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // Hide
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do this : 

spiner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adView, View view,int pos, long id) {

              selectedoption = adapter.get(pos);

              if(selectedoption == rb1)
                    {
                     rb1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }
    });
```